# Why "npm outdated" is not working as expected for Vite project

Tags: npm, vite, npm-outdated

I have recently switched from the usual react setup (`npx create-react-app .`) to `Vite`. and now I can't properly see the outdated package when I run `npm outdated`

Is there a way to still see the outdated packages instead of just seeing the version of Vite when I run `npm outdated`?

also, is it even the way it should be or is it just for me?

when I am in the directory of the Vite project and run `npm outdated` from the terminal before installing npm packages, it does list down all the outdated packages as expected.
but when I install the packages it starts to show only the Vite package as the result of `npm outdated` command.

[npm outdated - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxBpU.png)

Thanks.